# in R evaluate fit like a formula

Tags: r

in R, if I have this fit

```
x <- c(0,var_moda,1)
b <- c(v1, v2, v3)
p2_fit <- lm( b ~ poly(x, 2))
```

how I can use the fit like a formula?

maybe some this

```
p2_fit(0.5)
```

Comment: Are you looking for `predict`?

Comment: Do you want the value of the `b` given `x=0.5`?  If so, @Roland has it.

Comment: @Roland with `predict` I get three values `predict(p2_fit, 0.5)
        1         2         3 
0.8917749 1.0000000 1.1341991 `

Comment: I suggest to study the helpfile (`?predict.lm`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do note that the `newdata` argument of `predict.lm` requires

> an optional data frame in which to look for variables with which to predict.  If omitted, the fitted values are used.

You supplied a length 1 numeric vector. R **should** have thrown an error about `x` not being found and it does this if I do as you claim you did in your comment. Returning the fitted values is what usually happens when you forget to supply `newdata`.

You want something like

```
predict(p2_fit, newdata = data.frame(x = 0.5))
```

The name of `x` is important. It **must** match with the variable(s) on the right hand side of the formula.